# Member Photo only displays when inside channel tag pairs

Tags: channel-entries, members

I'm simply trying to display member photos, but cannot get my custom member group photos to display.

I am using the following code:

```
<span id="member-photo">
  <img src="{photo_url}" alt="{username}">
</span>
```

If I do this outside of a tag entry pair, I get the following code:

```
<span id="member-photo">
  <img src="{photo_url}" alt="adminname">
</span>
```

But if I put this inside of a channel entry I get the proper:

```
<span id="member-photo">
    <img alt="adminname" src="http://local.domain.com/uploads/member/photos/photo_1.png">
</span>
```

The problem is that when inside of the channel entry tag pair, it will show only the author of that entry's photo. How can I get this to show the logged in member's photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the images were not displaying is because they needed to be wrapped in EE's *custom profile data* tag pairs. The following code is the fix:

```
{exp:member:custom_profile_data}
    <span id="member-photo">
            <img src="{photo_url}" alt="{username}">
    </span>
{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
```